# Apache Log says: Deny - but it works (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am playing a little bit with htaccess to know apache with xampp.

I configured "AllowOverride All" for the whole / directory and the .htaccess files in the folders work properly.

I get excluded from a "private" folder, I get access to a "public" folder. But the log says something completely different.

For example Basic Authentication .htaccess:

```
# .htaccess for password
AuthType Basic
AuthName "password Folder is for password Folders"
AuthUserFile C:/xampp/htdocs/password/.htusers
Require valid-user
```

And I can login with correct passwords. But the log says it is denied !?

Apache Error Log:

> [Thu May 10 13:04:05 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by
>   server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/password/.htaccess [Thu May 10
>   13:04:05 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server
>   configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/password/.htusers

Why? It works as I can see - but why does the log tell me something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to question, may be possibly also a logging-bug in apache or xampp (i dont know), is to put files into the directories. If that happened the error message disappears.