# Apache 2.2: "Client denied by server configuration" - .htaccess password protection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, passwords, httpd.conf

I am having problems trying to set up a password in .htaccess file for a subdirectory on my server. After a long time it finally works as it supposed to but after each time I open the site in a browser the error appears in Apache error.log:
[Mon May 14 13:55:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/creativedesigner/.htaccess

Some of my httpd.conf:
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^.ht">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

And the .htaccess file:
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password"
AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/pass/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

Anyway - it works - I have to use correct user name and password to be able to see the site. But I'm preparing quite big project so i don't want any errors in future and something must be wrong to get this in the log. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh - I have asked the same question last week this must be a bug in Apache then:

[Apache Log says: Deny - but it works (htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532746/apache-log-says-deny-but-it-works-htaccess)